# submit button is not working on IE9

Tags: asp.net, webforms, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, submit

I have created a button which triggers the asp:uploadfile control there is a submit button which uploads the file to the server. After selected a file the submit button event is not firing on ie8, ie9 and ie10 . 
here's the code.

```
 <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="uploadcontrol" />
                        <asp:Button Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="Unnamed_Click" OnClientClick="sometask();"/>
                        <input type="button" value="hook" onclick="hook();"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
   </table>

<script>
    function hook() {
         document.getElementById("uploadcontrol").click();
    }
 </script>
```

Please Help i am stuck. 
thanks.

Comment: It's likely that it can't find the control if you are using a master page...  try `document.getElementById("<%= uploadcontrol.ClientID %>").click()` or using jQuery `$("#<%= uploadcontrol.ClientID %>").trigger("click");`

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that it can't find the control if you are using a master page...  try

```
document.getElementById("<%= uploadcontrol.ClientID %>").click()
```

or using jQuery

```
$("#<%= uploadcontrol.ClientID %>").trigger("click");
```